# Not able to installe ubuntu 14.04 version on windows 7 64 Bit 4 Gm Ram .

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

below are Errors on installing Ubuntu 14.04 version. How can this be resolved ?

04-04 20:41 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running get_metalink...
04-04 20:41 DEBUG  downloader: downloading 04-04 20:42 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink err=[Errno 4] IOError: 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Install Ubuntu _on_ Windows -> elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

you can download metalink files using download managers such as [this](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and [this](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) or if you're using firefox [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) will do.